# Variant of Stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have recently, for the first time, seen the following version of Stokes' theorem stated:

For a region $R$, $d\nu$ a volume element, $ds$ a surface element and $n(x)$ the unit normal to the surface at $x$, 
$$\int_R \text{grad} \, f(x) d\nu=\int_{\partial R} f(x) n(x) ds.$$

I am wondering how to obtain this from the standard variants of Stokes theorem. Thanks.

Comment: What are the standard variants of Stokes theorem that you are referring to?

Comment: whatever is on wikipedia or textbooks

Comment: That depends on which textbooks you look at. Do you mean $\int_{\partial M}\omega = \int_M d\omega$ or something more specific?

Comment: If there is an explanation via this formula then that would be wonderful